# limited resource for ProcessPoolExecutor (for example tcp port)

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

### Motivation:

I want to run some function (`myfunc` in the following example) for a large
number of values, and this function needs a free TCP port, and because the
number of TCP ports is limited I want to have only as many TCP ports as is the
number of worker processes.

> In reality, it runs a complex integration test which  runs for many seconds
> or minutes for each input value, it creates multiple processes which
> communicate using this port - that's why the port is necessary.
> For the purpose of this question, it's a limited resource which needs to be
> bound to a specific worker.
> I've simplified it to the following code which really doesn't need any TCP ports but
> my real code does and it is the core of my problem.

### Example:

If I had unlimited TCP ports, it could look like this:

```
import concurrent.futures
from typing import List, Tuple

PORT_BASE = 8000

def myfunc(param: Tuple[int, int]) -> str:
    port_offset, data = param
    port = PORT_BASE + port_offset
    return 'executing %d on port %d' % (data, port)

def main() -> None:
    n = 2
    values = range(20)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(n) as exe:
        print('\n'.join(exe.map(myfunc, enumerate(values))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But since I *do* have a limit on TCP ports I would like to "bind" a port to a
worker - but I don't know how to do that using `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

I would like to have (in context of the example above) only 2 TCP ports which
would be permanenly bound to 2 workers.

The main reason I'm using `ProcessPoolExecutor` is to avoid creating
`multiprocessing.Process`es, passing data using `multiprocessing.Queue`s,
joining processes, making sure all `Queue`s returned data, etc.

In fact I had exactly that and it was not reliable and it was a lot of code
(i.e. - a lot of bugs), so I would really, really like to switch to
`ProcessPoolExecutor` which in my experience "just works" with minimal code and is almost maintenance-free.

The only thing that prevents me from using `ProcessPoolExecutor` here is the need for limited resource - TCP ports.

### What have I tried:

1. using some "TCP port manager" which "lends" ports and then "takes them
   back" to be available for "lending" again, but this involves a lot of shared
   objects and communication and synchronization and in the end it's as much
   complex as the original "Processes+Queues" solution and probably wouldn't be very
   reliable
2. since python 3.7, `ProcessPoolExecutor` has `initializer` parameter, I
   thought could be used to set some "worker-specific" data, but as far as I
   understand, it can only modify global variables which is not useful for this case

### Question:

Is there any other way to set some "worker-specific" data and pass them to
`myfunc` using `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Or is my only hope going back to manually creating `Process`es and gluing them with `Queue`s?

Answer (score 1):

you were nearly there, to make sure each "task" will run on a separate worker you should use a [multiprocessing.Barrier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier) with slots equal to the number of workers, which will stop workers from grabbing more than one item from the task queue until each worker grabbed exactly one item (one resource)

a barrier can only be passed by inheritance, so it should be passed in the initializer, and the port that each process binds to needs to be saved as a global variable to be used in other functions.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import os
from typing import List, Tuple
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.synchronize

PORT_BASE = 8000

def myfunc(param: Tuple[int, int]) -> str:
    global port
    # if this next line fails it will throw,
    # and you should handle it by terminating and restarting the pool
    sync_barrier.wait(timeout=5)      
    port_offset, data = param
    port = PORT_BASE + port_offset
    return 'executing %d on port %d in process %d' % (data, port, os.getpid())

def do_work(i):
    print(f"doing work {i} on port {port} in process {os.getpid()}")
def initializer_fn(barrier: multiprocessing.synchronize.Barrier):
    global sync_barrier
    sync_barrier = barrier
def main() -> None:
    n = 2
    values = range(n)
    barrier = multiprocessing.Barrier(n)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(n,
                                                initializer=initializer_fn,
                                                initargs=(barrier,)) as exe:
        print('\n'.join(exe.map(myfunc, enumerate(values),chunksize=1)))
        exe.map(do_work,range(5))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
executing 0 on port 8000 in process 15024
executing 1 on port 8001 in process 14796
doing work 0 on port 8001 in process 14796
doing work 1 on port 8000 in process 15024
doing work 2 on port 8001 in process 14796
doing work 3 on port 8000 in process 15024
doing work 4 on port 8001 in process 14796
```

to be honest nothing in multiprocessing "just works", python makes it look simple, but it's never that simple, and it's too easy to shoot yourself in the foot with it.

Comment: Thanks! that looks like it should work, I'll accept if no better solution comes

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better solution than the one suggested by Ahmed AEK - it's
based on `Process.name` - I can get current process name and then parse the
number and use it as a port offset.

Process names are usually `Process-1, Process-2, ...` but I found that
`ProcessPoolExecutor` created `ForkedProcess-1` names so I just use anything
after the dash:

##### Update - this solution has problems when other processes are run elsewhere - the process names won't start at `1` - see Ahmed AEK's comment - better solution using custom context is below

```
import concurrent.futures
from multiprocessing import current_process
from typing import List, Tuple

PORT_BASE = 8000

def myfunc(data: int) -> str:
    proc_name = current_process().name
    proc_n_str = proc_name[proc_name.find('-') + 1:]
    proc_n = int(proc_n_str)
    port = PORT_BASE + proc_n
    return '%s: executing %d on port %d' % (proc_name, data, port)

def main() -> None:
    n = 2
    values = range(20)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(n) as exe:
        print('\n'.join(exe.map(myfunc, values)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
ForkProcess-1: executing 0 on port 8001
ForkProcess-2: executing 1 on port 8002
ForkProcess-1: executing 2 on port 8001
ForkProcess-2: executing 3 on port 8002
ForkProcess-1: executing 4 on port 8001
ForkProcess-2: executing 5 on port 8002
ForkProcess-1: executing 6 on port 8001
ForkProcess-2: executing 7 on port 8002
ForkProcess-1: executing 8 on port 8001
ForkProcess-2: executing 9 on port 8002
ForkProcess-1: executing 10 on port 8001
ForkProcess-2: executing 11 on port 8002
ForkProcess-1: executing 12 on port 8001
ForkProcess-2: executing 13 on port 8002
ForkProcess-2: executing 14 on port 8002
ForkProcess-1: executing 15 on port 8001
ForkProcess-2: executing 16 on port 8002
ForkProcess-1: executing 17 on port 8001
ForkProcess-2: executing 18 on port 8002
ForkProcess-1: executing 19 on port 8001
```

It's not perfect, because I feel that relying on process names is a bit
fishy, but it works very well and if it stops, I'll do this:

1. prepare multiprocessing context (based on `multiprocessing.get_context()`)
   which creates custom Process with preset `port` parameter
2. pass the context to the `ProcessPoolExecutor`
3. read `current_process().port` in worker

### Updated solution based on comments:

As Ahmed AEK pointed out, if any other processes gets created anywhere else, I
can't rely on process names to start with one, so here is the solution with
custom context which should guarantee correct ports (I've limited it to ForkContext, since I don't need anything other than linux compatibility, but I think it shouldn't be hard to update to use SpawnContext):

```
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing as mp

PORT_BASE = 8000

def myfunc(data: int) -> str:
    proc = mp.current_process()
    return '%s: executing %d on port %d' % (proc.name, data, proc.port)

def main() -> None:
    n = 2
    values = range(20)

    # this is used to make sure process names of `exe2` won't start at 1
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(100) as exe1:
        _ = ', '.join(exe1.map(str, range(100)))

    port_to_assign = PORT_BASE

    class ProcessWithPort(mp.context.ForkProcess):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            nonlocal port_to_assign
            self.port = port_to_assign
            port_to_assign += 1

    class MyContext(mp.context.ForkContext):
        Process = ProcessWithPort

    ctx = MyContext()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(n, mp_context=ctx) as exe2:
        print('\n'.join(exe2.map(myfunc, values)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output:

```
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 0 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-102: executing 1 on port 8001
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 2 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 3 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 4 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-102: executing 5 on port 8001
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 6 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 7 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-102: executing 8 on port 8001
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 9 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 10 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-102: executing 11 on port 8001
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 12 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 13 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-102: executing 14 on port 8001
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 15 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-102: executing 16 on port 8001
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 17 on port 8000
ProcessWithPort-102: executing 18 on port 8001
ProcessWithPort-101: executing 19 on port 8000
```

Comment: removing the barrier because it can raise is like removing the fire alarm because it could make noise .... your code has no guarantee that it will work, a single worker can execute the entire 20 functions if for any reason there was a small delay in the startup of the second one, the problem only grows when you scale it to more workers, your code is relying on the "process counter" which may change if any code ran before this code that spawned any worker, you also lost any configurability, and you are just relying that "code worked once so it must work everytime !" which is not true.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I don't see any problems which you talk about - each `myfunc` run is guaranteed a port number which is unique to it's process (i.e. worker process) - I'm only relying on process naming convention - which I can fix by using the context and custom `Process` if neccessary. It's quite robust linking between (worker) process and a port. And it didn't worked just once - it's now in "beta" testing and it has already run with many different data sets with results same as the previous version. But maybe I've missed something, I welcome all criticism

Comment: as i have already said, there is no guarantee in the above code that each of the workers will be assigned a port number, and just because it works now on your machine doesn't mean it will work later on another machine or operating system on a loaded system, this is a fact, not criticism, put the barrier back.

Comment: using the process counter may work now when you have a single script, that starts, does some work, then terminates python, but if this code is used in another context, the number you get is not guaranteed either, now you get worker `0,1,2,3`, but in the future if the code was integrated into something else that uses multiprocessing you will get worker `41,42,43` for example, if this might break your code then you should be careful of that, your code just doesn't have predictable behavior, i am only telling you that to spare you hours of debugging later.

Comment: @AhmedAEK - thanks, that's valid point, even though in my case, this is really isn't too much of a problem (it's a top-level script) - but I agree that this may be a problem in future, so I will modify it to use custom Processes with a custom context - I'll update the answer and I would welcome any further comments/criticism from you (or anyone). Thanks again!